# In Laravel Backpack version 4, the menu items of pagemanager does not save changes

Tags: laravel-backpack

When we create a new menu item it adds it but the "Type" and "Page" field does not get saved in the DB. Save happens for editing.
This used to work fine in the previous version.

[image: Form field that does not save]

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately we no longer have support for Backpack v4, however you could check if you have any errors in the Laravel log or in the console, perhaps providing more details of the problem could guide you towards the solution.

Cheers.